# How to convert this css to less

Tags: css, less

What method would you use to convert the following css into more dry less code:

```
nav ul,
nav ol,
ul.reset,
ol.reset {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing. That CSS/LESS is great and there isn't a nicer/DRYer way to write it in LESS.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could think of:

```
.resetList() {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav {
    ul, ol {
        .resetList;
    }
}
ul, ol {
    &.reset {
        .resetList;
    }
}
```

However because of the way mixins work the above would compile to this:

```
nav ul,
nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.reset,
ol.reset {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

So I would agree with [@ascii-lime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989589/552067) that pure CSS is probably the better route for something this simple. Hopefully less will provide an alternative in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It won't help much if you want to convert it into `LESS`.
The code will instead become longer by using LESS techniques. It's better to keep it the way it is.

If you still wish to do this, you can try this:

```
nav {

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    ul, ol {

        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        &.reset {

            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It will work? Thanks for sharing your knowledge, first time I am seeing a css like this...

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny Yeah. It will work. You can check out [LESS](lesscss.org). LESS is a stylesheet preprocessor. So you can play around with your stylesheet in a better manner :)

Comment: I tried the following code in a html page, butnot working. can you help me to find error
<style type="text/css">
table {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 border:1px double #FF0000;

     td {
  background:#3300FF;
    }

}
</style>

Comment: That won't output the same css. your less requires all `.reset` classes to be children of a `<nav>` element to be styled, and your example is nothing close to being dry.